# Sending request with Socket returning empty response

Tags: c#, sockets

I need to send an XML request over `Socket`. Here is my `C#` code that I am using. I tried to Debug and my `temp1` `byte[]` does have a data, but the response from Provider side is empty. They say that there is no request from y side:

```
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress[] ips;
ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(strURL);
IPAddress ipcha = ips[0];
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipcha, 1984);
server.Connect(ip); //Connect to provider server
byte[] temp1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtXML.Text.Trim());
server.Send(temp1); //Send data to server
byte[] data = new byte[2048];            
int receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data); //Read provider response
string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
txtResult.Text = strData;
```

Response is EMPTY. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion and not a solution to your problem: Check out [Lidgrens](https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) .Net network library. Makes you life alot easier regarding network communication in .Net

Comment: What are you calling "Response" here? do you mean `receivedDataLength` is `0`? or `strData` is an empty string? or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell both `receivedDataLength` is `0` and `strData` is empty

Comment: @Shohin that means: the server closed it's outbound socket without sending you anything.

Comment: @MarcGravell so is it something to do on my side or on Provider side?

Comment: @Shohin how can I answer that? I have no idea what the comms are here.

Comment: I suggest you use a sniffer such as Wireshark, on your side first to see that the request you think you are sending is actually being sent and to the correct address/port. If that is happening, (assuming you can) put a sniffer on the server side and see if the request is being received.